# I have used CSV file in Jmeter script. Now I want if data is Not read from CSV file then it will pick some Default Value. How to do this?

Tags: function, csv, jmeter

I have used CSV file in Jmeter script. But Jmeter is Not reading data from CSV File. Now I want if data is Not read from CSV file then it will pick Default Value. How to do this ? Any Function for doing this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT**

In JMeter 4.1  you will have the option to select default value with [__V](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__V) function.

For example, for variable `A` give default value NOT_FOUND

```
${__V(A,NOT_FOUND)}
```

Until JMeter team will enhance such feature, You can use a work around using [Regular Expression Extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Regular_Expression_Extractor) which have option to get variable name and set default:

Choose radio button `JMeter Variable Name to use`

> extraction is to be applied to the contents of the named variable

Choose your JMeter variable as `a` and put it also in `Name of created variable`

choose relevant regular expression as `(\w+)` Template `$1$` and Match No. 1 to get variable if exists

If not exists put in `Default Value` the default value you want as `AAAA`

[image]

Comment: Thank you so uch for your valuable reply.

Comment: It is giving me "id" text sometimes when I am running my script. It it not picking up the value I have used in Default Value section.

Comment: @Mukta Gupta It may occurr if your first line contains headers names and/or in certain line your columns number isn't correct

Comment: But I am getting "id" when I am running script from Non-GUI mode, in GUI mode it is working fine and picking up default values correctly.

Comment: @Mukta Gupta Please ask a new question with more details but with minimal requirements to reproduce it

Answer (score 0):

The only thing I can think of is using [__groovy() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__groovy) like:

```
${__groovy(vars.get('foo') != null ? vars.get('foo') : 'bar',)}
```

Where:

- `foo` - reference name of the variable (i.e. from CSV or wherever else)
- `bar` - default value
- `vars` - shorthand for [JMeterVariables](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/threads/JMeterVariables.html) class instance providing read/write access to all JMeter Variables.

More information: [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black)