# Can I override User Variables in Test Fragment

Tags: jmeter

I have a JMeter script that has a test fragment. I want to be able to set default values in case the Thread calling it doesn't provide a value. How would I override variables, or set them to default values?

Preferably without a JSR.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49273179/i-have-used-csv-file-in-jmeter-script-now-i-want-if-data-is-not-read-from-csv-f/49357556#49357556

Answer (score 0):

Not my favorite solution but here is what I am using in my http sampler `${__groovy( vars.get("test") ? vars.get("test")  : 'DEFAULT STRING')}`

Answer (score 0):

Use the Elvis operator `?:`, like:

`vars.get("test") ?: 'DEFAULT STRING'`

See [Groovy Default Value for variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73589546/groovy-default-value-for-variables) for details.

Or better: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49276582/2125837