# Groovy Default Value for variables

Tags: variables, groovy, variable-assignment, default-value

In Groovy we can assign ***default values*** to parameters in a ***method***, like this:

```
def say(msg = 'Hello', name = 'world') {
    "$msg $name!"
}
```

However, what's the simplest way to assign default values for variable assignments, when they are not from the method parameters, like environment variables or JMeter variables, as in [Can I override User Variables in Test Fragment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49819913/can-i-override-user-variables-in-test-fragment)?

Is this the only way?

`def mySession = System.getenv("SESSIONNAME") ? System.getenv("SESSIONNAME") : "Session Default"`

Is there any other ways, like in NodeJS syntax:

`def mySession = System.getenv("SESSIONNAME") || "Dfault"`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the Elvis operator `?:` that uses the provided value if it satisfies Groovy truth.

```
def mySession = System.getenv("SESSIONNAME") ?: "Dfault"
```

It will work unexpectedly and use the default value if the provided value exists and is e.g. `false` or `[]`, but for all non-empty/non-false values it will work.

https://groovy-lang.org/operators.html#_elvis_operator